# Why is Total internal energy of a system or external energy only the sum of kinetic and potential?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

Why is Total internal energy of a system or external energy only the sum of kinetic and potential ?
Why not some some other quantity as well present.

Is it because there can be only scenarios present.
Energy possessed by a body due to virtue of its motion and other at rest?

Comment: i think that your prof might have used total mechanical energy insetad of total internal energy

Comment: We were talking about heat transfer.So he used total internal energy actually.

Comment: But my question was that is there a chance that we may miss some form of energy when calculating total energy of any system.@Anonymous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total energy does indeed include all portions of energy, not just kinetic and potential but also thermal, chemical etc. and everything which is contained in the body.

But it is rarely all relevant. Typically you would only find the total energy in order to use the energy conservation law. And there, only an energy *difference* is actually important. So you can spare yourself from the tough internal energies often in your calculation and only include the energies that may be changing.

Comment: What if there are some other energies which we don’t know yet ?

Comment: How do we identify that you know , there are no other forms of energy which we can consider.Is there some device telling us that there are no other changes happened ?

Comment: Or Is it like we think about all forms of energy which we think can be considered.

Comment: @user279337 You include those that are relevant. And that is a choice from experience and expertise, yes. For instance in classical mechanical circumstances, it is well known which energies that will be involved. We would there typically ignore/neglect heat generation and thus not have to consider, say thermal energy changes. And with no material changes, we would typically ignore all internal changes as well and also magnetic influences, solar irradiation and such. We simply ignore those whose changes presumably are negligible - and that is an educated estimate/guess. ...

Comment: ...  In some scenarios we can't ignore internal changes, such as during car crashes where energy is spent on deforming materials, melting/burning objects and ripping apart chemical structures. Or simply when friction is involved which generates heat. Then the energy conservation law is not useful since we then don't know the total energy, unless we have other means (special formulas or measurements) to know exactly how much energy that is being converted between those various forms.

Comment: Ok.Really helpful.A simple question I have.Is there maybe 2% chance that we may don’t know if there is some other energy present or it may have got included in the formula but we don’t it’s exact value.

Comment: Or what is it actually .

Comment: @user279337 After centuries of work with energy, especially in mechanics, we are fairly certain about which energies that are or may be involved. Several of them have been investigated and studied for formulas, relationships and other behaviour. It is always possible that something unknown is happening in a new situation. But with the already known energies, we have seen how they match up perfectly with so many other similar mechanical control scenarios. If we weren't sure, it wouldn't be likely that skyscrapers and bridges would hold. So we are fairly sure.

Comment: Ok.Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @user279337 No problem, glad to be of help.